# Particle Creation and Energy Momentum Tensor DIvergence

Tags: general-relativity, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Reading into QFT in curved spacetime, you could find claims that in time-dependent and extremely curved spacetime backgrounds, particles could be created.

How is particle creation compatible with the notion of a divergence free Energy-Momentum tensor? We should now have:
$$\nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu \nu}≠0$$
Could someone clarify how I am wrong or how how this inconsistency (since the Einstein tensor is divergence free) is alleviated in QFTCS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *covariantly* conserved energy momentum tensor  does not automatically lead to a conserved 4-momentum i.e such that
$$
P^i=\int_{\hbox{time slice}} T^{0i} dx^3
$$
is independent of the time slice. For that you need a *symmetry* and its associated Killing vector $\xi$. If $\xi$ obeys the Killing vector property
$$
\nabla_\mu \xi_\nu+\nabla_\nu \xi_\mu=0
$$ then
$$
p^\mu= {T^\mu}_\nu\xi^\nu
$$
has a   time slice independent "charge"
$$
\frac {d}{dt} \int_{\hbox{time slice}} p^0 d^3 x=0.
$$
A timelike Killing vector will lead  a conserved energy, and spacelike one to a conserved momentum In the absence of a Killing isometry there is no conserved energy or momentum, and so nothing to stop particle creation.

Comment: Do you know of any books which talk about Killing Fields and conserved quantities? This would be a very useful reference for me...

Comment: About any GR book would do so I think.